# Attribute Error with Rails Nested Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've spent hours on this one. I'm trying to use Ryan Bate's nested_form_for
plugin in rails 3.2 though I don't think it's related to my issue. I tried
taking it out and I still get the same issue.

When I hit **organizations/:org_id/publications/new** I see the form to add a new
publication correctly. However, when I submit (with or without correct data) it
I get an `unknown attribute: publications_attributes` error. I'm sure there's
something wrong with the way I'm building the related object(s) in the create
method. Any ideas?

#### models/organization.rb

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,
                  :publications_attributes, # fk, nested form
  has_many :publications
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :publications,
                                :allow_destroy => true
```

#### models/publication.rb

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :link,
                  :organization_id
  belongs_to :organization
  validates :link,
            :presence => true,
end
```

#### controllers/publications_controller.rb

```
class PublicationsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @organization = current_user.organizations.first
    @organization.publications.build
  end

  def create
    @organization = current_user.organizations.first
    @organization.publications.build(params[:organization])
    if @organization.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created publications"
      redirect_to @organization
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

#### routes.rb

```
resources :organizations do
  resources :publications,  :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

#### views/publications/new.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for @organization, :html => { :novalidate => 'novalidate' },
                                   :method => :post,
                                   :url => organization_publications_path, do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

  <%= f.fields_for :publications do |publication_form| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'publications/form', :locals => { :f => publication_form } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add", :publications %>

  <%= render :partial => 'shared/submit', :locals => { :text => 'Create', :f => f } %>
<% end %>
```

#### views/publications/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :link %>
  <%= f.text_field :link %>
</div>
<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
```

The submitted hash looks like this:

```
Parameters: {
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"rhW/m8mnulZMmW7gkLYxOT8RWYoQc8eYdp2hOXkqHPU=",
    "organization"=>{
        "publications_attributes"=>{
            "0"=>{
                    "link"=>"fdsfdsfs"
            }
        }
    },
    "commit"=>"Create",
    "organization_id"=>"53"
}
```

Comment: Can you add your params as they appear in your log file above, could be an alignment issue.  I would grab them and try the build/create in the rails console as the lowest common denominator.

`user = User.first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, ignore my previous answer. This is a little different than what I have done in the past, but since the organization already exists you can just call update_attributes on that. Rails (3.2 at least) will loop through all the publication_attributes and add new ones or update existing ones. In the create method try this...

```
if @organization.update_attributes(params[:organization])
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created publications"
  redirect_to @organization
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

Comment: Looks like this is the answer! I also managed to get it to work using    `@organization.publications_attributes=(params[:organization][:publications_attributes])` but your solution seems way simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@organization.publications.build(params[:organization])
```

I think this tries to set publications_attributes on a publication, try

```
@organization.publications.build(params[:organization][:publication_attributes])
```

Comment: That won't work because `[:publications_attributes]` is a collection. But calling `@organization.publications_attributes = params[:organization][:publications_attributes]` should instead.

Answer (score 0):

See it now

second line of your create

```
@organization.publications.build(params[:organization])
```

Should be

```
@organization.new(params[:organization])
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error. If it's any help adding a `publications_attributes=` method to the Publication model fixes the error but it then never seems to save (always invalid)